# C++ : Program fails during vector filling and searching

Tags: c++, vector

I'm practicing `C++ vector` and as an exercise I want to fill a vector with 16 million random numbers and then find the position of the first occurrence of a number. The code which I implemented so far is this:

```
int getIndexOf(std::vector<int>& v, int num) {
    for(std::size_t i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if(v.at(i) == num) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {

    int searchedNumber = 42;
    int vectorSize = 16000000;
    std::vector<int> v(vectorSize);
    for(std::size_t i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        v.push_back(rand() % 10000000);
    }

    //Linear search
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    int position = getIndexOf(v, searchedNumber);

    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "The linear search took: " << duration.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The number " << searchedNumber << " occur first at position " << position << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Additionally I measure the time just for some statistics. The problem is that the program crash with error **bad_alloc** which I link with *Running out of stack space*. So initially I though that filling a vector with so many numbers  when the vector is on the stack will be a reason for the crash and I created the vector dynamically (pointer). However, I still get the same error. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Please note that `rand() % 10000000` may produce far from random values, if `RAND_MAX` in your [implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/cpp/c-runtime-library/rand-max?view=msvc-160) is less than 10000000. Consider using a more [modern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) pseudo-random number generator and a distribution like [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: Regarding the randomness, C++ have plenmty of good [(pseudo) random number generation facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), much better than `rand`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    int vectorSize = 16000000;
    std::vector<int> v(vectorSize);
    for(std::size_t i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        v.push_back(rand() % 10000000);
    }
```

This part is bad. `push_back()` adds an element to the vector, so it increases `size()`. Therefore, this loop won't terminate until something bad happens.

You should do like this instead:

```
    int vectorSize = 16000000;
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(vectorSize); // allocate memory without actually adding elements
    for(int i=0; i < vectorSize; i++) { // use the known size
        v.push_back(rand() % 10000000);
    }
```

Comment: Or, since the size is set in the original code, use `v[i] = rand() % 10000000;` instead of `push_back`.

Comment: Don't you know the pain and suffering caused by all these sloppy postfix increment operators in for loops? Compilers shake their heads every time.